# When specifying passwordFormat for credentials in web.config, how do you handle decryption?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

If I setup my app to use forms authentication, and I specify the credentials in web.config like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" defaultUrl="~/AuthArea" timeout="2880">
    <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
      <user name="user" password="user123" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

How do I then, in my LogOn Action validate the credentials?

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password)) {
```

Won't I need to encrypt the user entered password using MD5?  And if so, how do you do that?

Thanks.

Comment: it's not hard-coded if it's in an app.config ;)

Comment: okay well anyway, how would I Authenticate it?

Comment: I updated the title to reflect the actual question.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you don't use MD5.  It's pretty weak and the hash is relatively easy to crack within minutes using free software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to encrypt the password when you are using FormsAuthentication.Authenticate.  Your password in the web.config will need to be encrypted in MD5 though.  here is the code I use:

```
public static string EncryptToMD5(this string helper)
        {
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(helper)));
        }
```

Comment: So are you saying do this: EncryptToMD5(model.Password);  or are you saing to use that method to figure out what the MD5 is, and then use that string in the web.config?

Comment: Use the code in a unit test and encrypt the user123 password, then place the encrypted string in the web.config under the password.

Comment: Basically, your line <credentials passwordFormat="MD5"> is just telling .NET how your password is encrypted.  You store the encryped password in the password credetial in the web.config.  Then when you call .Authenticate() it automatically takes the password, converts it to MD5 and then compares it to the MD5 in the web.config.

Comment: And one final note, MD5 is not meant to be decrypted, it is a one way hash.  This is why it is great for passwords.

Comment: One final note, this is the MD5 hash for user123 6ad14ba9986e3615423dfca256d04e3f

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write (or modify) the Security Provider to encrypt the password and compare it against the credentials that are stored.  My biggest advice to you is start from an existing security provider like the SqlServerRoleProvider (which is wired up in all the new MVC / Web Forms projects as the default provider).

Details can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx

FYI:  The security providers that M$ provides handles encryption BY DEFAULT.  This means you don't have to custom write it :-)  I'd say start with a SQL Server Membership Provider example and database tables and branch out from there.

Comment: You're missing my point.  I'm specifying users/passwords in the web.config.